# How can I use filtered with function_score tag

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I have defined below mapping.

```
  "mappings": {
    "test_type": {
      "properties": {
        "itemname": {
          "type": "string",
          "store":"yes",
          "index": "analyzed",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "categoryid": {
          "type": "long",
          "store":"yes"
        }
        "myrank": {
          "type": "long",
          "store":"yes"
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

Mainly, I want to search the "itemname" field.
And also I want to custom score result like this.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "score_mode": "multiply",
      "functions": [
        "script_score": {
          "script": "_score * 0.7 + doc[\"myrank\"].value / 100 * 0.3"
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "test",
          "default_field": "itemname",
          "default_operator": "and"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ]
}
```

I know it works as I expected.

Sometimes I want to search using both itemname and categoryid fields.
But I can't use the "filtered" tag with function_score.
I know that if I use filtered tag only, it works like this.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "itemname",
          "query": "*"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "categoryid": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ]
}
```

I have tried making many type of combination tags between filtered and function_score, but I couldn't get success.

I mean I want to make a DSL like this SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM test_type WHERE itemname LIKE "%xxxx%" AND categoryid = 1 ORDER BY "_score * 0.7 + doc[\"myrank\"].value / 100 * 0.3"
```

Does anyone know what should I do use both filtered and function_score or is there another way to do filter ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try function score with filter like this ?

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "score_mode": "multiply",
      "functions": [
        "filter": { "term": { "categoryid": "1" }},
        "script_score": {
          "script": "_score * 0.7 + doc[\"myrank\"].value / 100 * 0.3"
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "test",
          "default_field": "itemname",
          "default_operator": "and"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE:**

- The field categoryId should not be analysed if you are using term
  filter on it. Change your mapping to make it not analyzed.
- Use a filtered query to filter based on categoryId.

Can you please try the below query ?

```
   "query":{  
      "function_score":{  
         "query":{  
            "filtered":{  
               "query":{  
                  "query_string":{  
                     "default_field":"itemname",
                     "query":"*"
                  }
               },
               "filter":{  
                  "term":{  
                     "categoryid":"1"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "boost_mode":"replace",
         "score_mode":"multiply",
         "script_score": {
           "script": "_score * 0.7 + doc[\"myrank\"].value / 100 * 0.3"
         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I have already tried like this DSL. In this case, the DSL has no error, but I got datas which have not only "categoryid = 1" but any other categoryi

Comment: Could you tell me that do you think I have some mistakes for example mapping define or something like that ?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it. But I couldn't get data as I expected.

Comment: sorry, I might have some mistakes. I got success. Thank you for your great help!
But the DSL is a little different. This is the correct DSL.

Comment: {
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "default_field": "itemname",
              "query": "*"
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "categoryid": "3"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "score_mode": "multiply",
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "_score * 0.7 + doc[\"myrank\"].value / 100 * 0.3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}